# Trouble with error message in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, error-handling, react-hook-form

I'm looking to implement the React Hook Error Message v7, but I've some problem with the styling. I'm trying to make the error message appear like the one in the documentation (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-errormessage-jufsl?file=/src/index.js) but it doesn't seem to be working and it keeps appearing twice as well. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} id="contactform">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
        name="name"
        {...register("name", {
          required: "Name is Required",
          minLength: {
            value: 3,
            message: "Please enter your name"
          }
        })}
      />
    <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="name" as="p" />
    <ErrorMessage
      errors={errors}
      name="name"
      render={({ message }) => <p>{message}</p>}
     />
      <input
        type="tel"
        placeholder="Mobile Number"
        name="mobile"
      />
/form
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears twice because you call the component twice.

you've to remove

```
<ErrorMessage
  errors={errors}
  name="name"
  render={({ message }) => <p>{message}</p>}
/>
```